# Can't render a plotly chart when using fetch

Tags: javascript, django

I have a chart that renders fine when loading the whole page, but if I use `fetch` to update data it doesn't render:
Here are my views:

```
def analytics(request):
    data = get_chart(60)
    context = {
        'chart': data['chart'],
    }
    return render(request, 'app/analytics.html', context)


def get_chart(request):
    is_ajax = request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
    if is_ajax:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            data = get_chart(int(request.GET.get('interval')))
            return JsonResponse({'chart': data['chart'], })
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'Invalid request'}, status=400)
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('Invalid request')
```

Here's template:

```
<div class="row justify-content-start mb-2">
  <div class="col"><a href="javascript:;" class="chart_scale" data-foo="1">1m</a></div>
  <div class="col"><a href="javascript:;" class="chart_scale" data-foo="60">1h</a></div>
</div>
<div class="row bg-light p-3 rounded justify-content-center align-items-center" id="chart">
  {{chart|safe}}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var chart = document.getElementById('chart')

const chart_scales = document.getElementsByClassName('chart_scale')
for (const button of chart_scales) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    url = '/analytics/update/?interval=' + e.target.dataset.foo
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data['chart'])
      chart.innerHTML = data['chart']
    })
  })
}

</script>
```

I get the data both times, it's length is the same, but if I inspect the element after the fetch update I get empty `div`:

```
<div id="my_chart" class="plotly-graph-div" style="height:768px; width:1024px;"></div>
```

What am I missing?

***UPDATE***
The console output looks like this:
[image]

Does the fact that half of it is red mean anything?

Comment: What does the console show?

Comment: Is data['chart'] a string, an image, another object? If it's just an object perhaps try turning it into a string or similar before trying to set it to inner HTML

Comment: What it is supposed to.

Comment: I tried using toString() and JSON.stringify(), didn't work.

Comment: @Viktor, can you share what data['chart'] is in a code block?

Comment: @Oak Updated the post with the console log. Can it be too big for a fetch request?

Comment: I see, so it's a whole set of HTML. I don't know enough about Django, but I imagine the initial load document is being assembled and then rendered in one go on load. Whereas when you are call inner HTML there must be an issue with characters not being escaped or similar breaking things when you set innerHTML

Perhaps copy and check that HTML over in an IDE, and do some tests locally?

I also think scripts inserted via innerHTML won't run, you have to use `eval` or similar which is another fundamental issue.